# Error while updating the maven project from Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

HI I developed maven project and trying to run automation scripts using Selenium Java with Eclipse.

But when I try to update Maven project from eclipse. I'm seeing below error.

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5

Comment: Also while creating new maven project from sractch the maven depenedencies are downloaed in eclipse and same error is displayed.

Comment: Hey Aditya, can you paste your `pom.xml`?

Comment: my pom.xml file is too long and can' be pasted here.

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>EmiratesNBD_FaceLift_Smoke</groupId>
  <artifactId>EmiratesNBD_FaceLift_Smoke</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>EmiratesNBD_FaceLift_Smoke suite</description>

Comment: <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
 <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.4</version> 
 <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency> 
 <dependency> 
 <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
 <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId> 
 <version>1.2.4</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>  
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
   <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies> </projects>

Comment: kindly edit your question and paste it there and format is properly! thanks!! otherwise your question will be banned automatically!'

Comment: Check your repositories in your <home>/.m2/settings.xml file.The maven-resources-plugin:2.5 is perfectly available from the Central repository.